JsonCpp problem with sorting output json - case / alphabetical problem
I have an issue with JsonCpp library in C++ and sorting of keys after the json is produced. I found that JsonCpp is ignoring alphabetical order if there is Lowercase and Uppercase difference. It always favors Uppercase first and then alphabetical order.
Lets say we have this code to produce
Json::Value aJsonResult(Json::objectValue);

aJsonResult["ShuttersOpen"] = "test";
aJsonResult["ShutterType"] = "test";
aJsonResult["ShutterWidth"] = "test";

Json::StreamWriterBuilder aBuilder;
aBuilder["indentation"] = "";
return Json::writeString(aBuilder, aJsonResult).c_str();

But this produces output below, notice how ShuttersOpen key is last, even though its not correct.
{
    "ShutterType": "test",
    "ShutterWidth": "test",
    "ShuttersOpen": "test"
}

Any ideas how to fix this, I could not find any documentation on the official site

generally json is not ordered. Why is this an issue?

because of unit tests, I need to have it uniformed across the solution

but if it is not ordered, why you want to test that it is ordered?

you can test equality modulo order, by first sorting then checking if its the same elements in the same order. Eg to check that "1,4,2" is same elements as "1,2,4" you sort it to get "1,2,4", then compare for equality "1,2,4" == "1,2,4".

okay, thing is, I am comparing this to the expected json string generated in c# and there is also different behaviour when producing json, so I need to have it the same, either in c++ or c#

what I said, when you want something unordered ordered you can sort it

Fix your tooling, you're depending on implementation details. One approach would be to use jq to pipe both expected and actual JSON through and then compare the result, so that you get similar formatting and ordering.

Just to confirm: JsonCpp has no way to impose order on map elements. nlohmann::json could be done that way, but I agree with others - unit tests should not add extra requirements to production code. If you have external JSON as expected value, parse it and compare parsed objects (ignoring order on map members).

The ordering of your json should not matter, what should matter is that you json contains the expected key/values. So your test is too strict

In lexicographical order, capital letters precede lowercase letters. "Z" < "a".

okay, got it, I was hoping there would something like in c# to make all keys lowercase and sort them when creating a json
